# Is PayPal's iOS SDK available outside the US or not?

Tags: paypal

Is PayPal's iOS SDK available outside the US or not?

The following has been added to the FAQ recently:

> Can I use the new mobile SDKs outside of the US?
>   Yes! The PayPal iOS SDK and Android SDK support all countries and currencies supported by the REST Payment API.

(ref: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/faq/#mobile-sdk-questions)

Yet all the old warnings still remain there too.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the availability of a SDK

Comment: It was phrased that way, however, What I actually was referring to was a discrepancy in using the SDK for none US countries due to the currency being USD. The answers still havn't really cleared it up, just added extra ambiguity

Answer (score 2):

The new Mobile SDKs are available in all countries where REST APIs are available as mentioned in the FAQs. Please see below the list of countries and country specific policies/process.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/

We will be fixing the discrepancies that have creeped in the docs asap.

Comment: So you mean that Mobile SDK are still available in USD only ? OR is now available in all ? Actually, today i am trying to integrate SDK with Canadian Dollar (CAD) but it didn't worked and same message appears "Available only in USD" ? Please clear.

Comment: yes, you can use only "USD", no other currency currenty

Comment: When will "Direct Credit Card Payments" be available for european countries (Germany, France, Italy, Spain) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is available.
I have integrated paypal in my app